# Call Amazon Web Services to submit xml file throws WebException The remote name could not be resolved https

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, system.net.webexception

I am building a tool to translate some CSV files into XML files and then upload them via the Amazon Web Services to upload products to a market place store.

I am testing the tool and the CSV to XML translation is fine and valid xml is created but I am having trouble calling the AWS services and sending the files. At the moment I can't even succesfully call the AWS service let alone try sending a file.

When I create a HttpWebRequest and try and call the method "GetRequestStream" I get a WebException:

"The remote name could not be resolved https"

There is no inner exception or anything useful to help me.

The properties I have set to the webRequest are

Address - https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Action=SubmitFeed&MarketplaceIdList.Id.1=MarketPlaceId&Merchant .................

Headers - 
+       Headers {User-Agent: Funkyrox/1.0 (Language=C#; =)
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-MD5: 4BDPHUko1//iVAdb5wr/Vw==
Host: mws.amazonservices.co.uk

}   System.Net.WebHeaderCollection

Host -
"mws.amazonservices.co.uk"

Method - POST

RequestUri -
https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Action=SubmitFeed&MarketplaceIdList.Id.1=MarketPlaceId&Merchant......................

There are others if needed as well.

When I ping https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk I get a response so I think the it's valid

I can't seem to find really useful examples of how to do this. I downloaded an C# tool from Amazon and have used a lot of the code in there but can't see how to call the service correctly.

Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I have seen the same thing occur and within my service, it never resolves without me stopping and restarting the service.

Comment: Afraid not and as a consequence we aren't using the services anymore